# Python regex named group starts with

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex pattern

```
r'^(?P<my_group>[-\w]+)'
```

this matches

`foo-bar` and `bar-foo`

But I want it to only match strings that start with 'fo' how do I do this for named groups?

I tried

```
r'^(?P<my_group>[[^fo]-\w]+)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't put it in square brackets (character classes), but outside them:

```
r'^(?P<my_group>fo[-\w]+)'
```

Your current regex is matching one of the characters in `[[^fo]` (i.e. `[^fo`) followed by a dash, a 'word character' and one or more `]`.

You can test out your regex on [this website](http://regex101.com/r/hX1fI4).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fo[\w-]+` instead of `[[^fo]-\w]+`.
You made a little mess with your character class. Inside square brackets you have to put the character you want to match (also as intervals, like `[a-z]`). If you want to match the `-`, it is good practice to put it at the end in the character class, to avoid confusion with intervals (so you should write something like `[a-d-]` to match `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and the `-`). 
If in a character class you put a `^` at the beginning, you want to match all the chars which are NOT listed, so `[^a-d-]` would match everything but `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and the `-`.
Pay attention that, outside a character class, `^` means beginning of the string.